# Retrofit not working on release version of app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit in my app. Everything is working fine but when I create the release version of the app some calls aren't working.

What could the problem be? I already disabled `minifyEnabled` in my gradle file.

**Edit:**
Found the real problem:
I get the user data by a specific API call. I map this on the following class:

```
String ID;
String user_login;
String user_nicename;
String user_email;
String display_name;
```

For some reason, all the fields are filled except for ID. When I don't use release but debug the ID field gets filled.

Comment: post your `build.gradle` and `Retrofit` codes

Comment: @Lingeshwaran I can't see any since its the release version.

Comment: set build variant to release and check it show error.

Comment: can you post your interface, model and handling code part?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
-dontnote okhttp3.**, okio.**, retrofit2.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
```

If above code not work then add `@Keep` annotation to your model class like this.

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class Blog {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For me, I was trying to fetch data using retrofit. My model was like following:

```
data class ChecksumResponseEntity(
    @SerializedName("code")
    val code: Double,
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String,
    @SerializedName("checksum")
    val checksum: String
)
```

The issue was that all values were being initialized to null instead of what was coming in response.

A added following in proguard file but it **did not** help me:

```
-dontnote okhttp3.**, okio.**, retrofit2.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
```

Than I tried adding @Keep annotation to my Model file as shown below:

```
@Keep
data class ChecksumResponseEntity(
    @SerializedName("code")
    val code: Double,
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String,
    @SerializedName("checksum")
    val checksum: String
)
```

Not sure why it was happening but **adding @Keep fixed it for me**.

Answer (score 3):

make sure have provided specific rules for retrofit.
If you've enabled `minifyEnabled=true`then

add below rules for retrofit in your `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-dontnote okhttp3.**, okio.**, retrofit2.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
```

Comment: There is no error. The problem is that when I debug the app everything works. I can login and all and then I get to see my name. When I use the release version the login works but I can't see my name.

Comment: @BartBergmans I am experiencing same. Any solution worked for you? all mentions in this post none worked.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the package as it is, where the DTOs are :

```
-keep class com.test.apppackagename.retrofit.dto** {
    *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Three possible solutions

### Solution 1: Preserve Model Classes with Proguard Rules

```
# Keep the model classes and their fields
-keep class com.example.myapp.model.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.example.myapp.model.** { *; }
```

In this case `com.example.myapp` is the package name.

### Solution 2: Use @Keep annotation

Use @Keep annotation of your model class. Like this:

```
package com.example.myapp.model;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class MyClass {

    String ID;
    String user_login;
    String user_nicename;
    String user_email;
    String display_name;
    
    // Rest of the code...
}
```

### Solution 3:

In app level `build.gradle` use

```
minifyEnabled false
```

### To test your app, utilize the following lines of code for release and debug configurations within your app's level build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    /*release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }*/
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```